# How to keep messages after deactivating imessage?

Tags: iphone, messages

I disabled imesseage (and removed the addresses) on my iphone 4. Afterwards, some old messages to some friends disappeared from my phone. I don't understand why.

I restored imessage and the addresses, and now the old messages are back. How can I disable imessage without losing the messages?

Answer (score 1):

In the morning, reactivating imessage, adding back the numbers, then disabling it **removing the numbers**, fixed it. I still have all my old messages.